# zend Navigation not right work cause zend router

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation, zend-router

my url is `http://mysite.com/index/bytype/id/5/name/ACTION`
when using zend router it'll be rewrite to `http://mysite.com/index/bytype/5.ACTION.html`
i was config in file router.ini like this:

```
routes.bytype.type       = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.bytype.route             = "bytype/(\d+).(.*).html"
routes.bytype.defaults.module       = "default"
routes.bytype.defaults.controller    = "index"
routes.bytype.defaults.action       = "bytype"
routes.bytype.map.1             = "id"
routes.bytype.map.2             = "name"
routes.bytype.map.3             = "page"

routes.bytype.reverse          = "bytype/%d.%s.html"
```

code above have issue when i click button next page , it not jump to next page, cause Parameter page/2 not avalable, zend router was rewrite my url become to `http://mysite.com/index/bytype/5.ACTION.html` again,
if not rewrite it maybe look like `http://mysite.com/index/bytype/id/5/name/ACTION/page/2`
so how can i including "page" parameter into url above with zend router.thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Try Zend routing on your `Bootstrap.php` file as an alternative.

Here is a tutorial on how to do that:

http://www.codexperience.co.za/post/hiding-url-parameters-names-using-zend-routers